# Building a Regex String - Any assistance provided

Tags: regex

Im very new to REGEX, I understand its purpose, but Im struggling to yet fully comprehend how to use it. Im trying to build a REGEX string to pull the **A8OP2B** out from the following (or whatever gets dumped in that 5th group).

**{"RfReceived":{"Sync":9480,"Low":310,"High":950,"Data":"A8OP2B","RfKey":"None"}}**

The other items in above line, will change in character length, so I cannot say the 51st to the 56th character. It will always be the 5th group in quotation marks though that I want to pull out.

Ive tried building various regex strings up, but its still mostly a foreign language to me and I still have much reading to do on it.

Could anyone provide me a working example with the above, so I can reverse engineer and understand better?

Thanks

Comment: This is just JSON. Why would you need to retrieve information from JSON using regex, instead of just using JSON like it was meant to?

Comment: `regex` is not the most appropriate tool for parsing complex formats. Even more, the data you posted is [JSON](http://json.org). Most programming languages nowadays either support JSON directly or have one or more libraries with functions to handle JSON properly.

Comment: This is pulled in from a MQTT broker into 3rd party software, whereby, my options to do something with the raw data, is limited to REGEX. In the 3rd party software, I just get the above line appear and the interface allows me to REGEX.

Im going to end up with about 40 different possible types of those lines appearing, each with its own 6 character string, so I need to filter out the rest of the bits, so the 3rd party software can translate the 6 digit code into an action/command within the 3rd party software.

If that makes sense?

Comment: To explain further..... I effectively get a console output if you will, that cannot run any kind of scripting language. All I can tell it to do, is, for each line that appears in the console, strip out certain text via REGEX (REGEX is all the console lets me do) and present that to the main program. Its a hardware device that sends this MQTT line, so I cannot change what it sends. The MQTT broker just relays it onto a programs console and the console can accept any text input, but cannot translate the line of text to just the area I want, or that the main program will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo 1:** Reference the JSON to a var, then use either dot or bracket notation.

**Demo 2:** Using RegEx is not recommended, but here's one in JavaScript:

```
/\b(\w{6})(?=","RfKey":)/g
```

#### First Match

1. *non-consuming match:* **:"A**

   **meta border:** **`\b`**: A non-word=**:**, any char=**"**, and a word=**A**
2. *consuming match:* **A8OP2B**

   **begin capture:** **`(`**, Any word =**`\w`**, 6 times=**`{6}`**
   **end capture:** **`)`**
3. *non-consuming match:* **","RfKey":**

   **Look ahead:** **`(?=`** **for:** **","RfKey":** **`)`**

---

### Demo 1

```js
var obj = {"RfReceived":{"Sync":9480,"Low":310,"High":950,"Data":"A8OP2B","RfKey":"None"}};

var dataDot = obj.RfReceived.Data;

var dataBracket = obj['RfReceived']['Data'];

console.log(dataDot);

console.log(dataBracket)
```

---

### Demo 2

**Note:** This is consuming a string of 3 consecutive patterns. 3 matches are expected.

```js
var rgx = /\b(\w{6})(?=","RfKey":)/g;

var str = `{"RfReceived":{"Sync":9480,"Low":310,"High":950,"Data":"A8OP2B","RfKey":"None"}},{"RfReceived":{"Sync":8080,"Low":102,"High":1200,"Data":"PFN07U","RfKey":"None"}},{"RfReceived":{"Sync":7580,"Low":471,"High":360,"Data":"XU89OM","RfKey":"None"}}`;

var res = str.match(rgx);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Appreciated, but my software wont let me do that. I effectively get a console output if you will, that cannot run that kind of scripting language. All I can tell it to do, is, for each line that appears in the console, strip out certain text via REGEX and present that to the main program. 

Its a hardware device that sends this MQTT line, so I cannot change what it sends. The MQTT broker just relays it onto a programs console and the console can accept any text input, but cannot translate the line of text to just the area I want, or that the main program will accept.

Comment: Ive managed to find a solution, that works for me. Im however going to mark you right for the JSON style solution (though I did managed to get what I need in from my console via its limitations).

Comment: @WS1234 See Demo 2

Comment: Thankyou!! Thats great :)